# java oracle get timestamp error ' The database session time zone is not set'

Tags: java, oracle, resultset

In my oracle database, my column name is: `CHARGED_DATE` and data type is `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`

I have a java oracle code trying to get that data:

```
    Connection reportDBConnection = null;
    try {
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"); 
        TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        reportDBConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1523/**", "@@","##");
    } catch (SQLException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println("date.."+resultSet.getTimestamp("charged_date"));
    }
```

I get the error:`java.sql.SQLException: The database session time zone is not set`

`resultSet.getTimestamp("charged_date")` is giving the error.
how do i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `java.sql.Timestamp getTimestamp(String columnLabel, Calendar cal)`